# Ajax success loop not showing last index value

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I have the follwing json result showing in console.
 [image]

I tried to display the result on a table like this.

[image]
But my result is taking only  0th and 1st index, it is not taking 2nd index value. The result is attached below.

[image]

I need three results but it is showing only 2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share you code

Comment: Possible to make fiddle ?

Comment: Use the index that the `$.each()` function supplies rather than your own. It may not fix your problem, but it's better for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue might me quite simple:

you are iterating on `res` and not on your arrays. `res` has only 2 elements, named `ad_name` and `expiry_date`.

when you loop on it, you will have only 2 loop turns. try loop on `res.ad_name` instead.

note: you would have maybe noticed the mistake if you had used your `index` and displayed it

Answer (score 1):

just remove the counter and use index and val try this:

```
$.each(res, function(index, val) {
   console.log(index +':'+val);
});
```

hope it's help,

Comment: Even the counter looks ok to me ?

Comment: just try it and you will got an output in browser console, then you can manage your display logic